# Emacs frame-inherited-parameters only partially work

Tags: frames

For the value of `frame-inherited-parameters`, I normally use `(top left width height)` so that new frames have the same geometry as `(selected-frame)`.

Since switching to Emacs 25.1.1, this no longer works completely.  Only *some* of the parameter values are copied to the new frame.

I run on MacOS Sierra.  (Therefore my `frame-creation-function` is the one in `term/ns-win.el`.)

If I start with a frame like this:

```
(#<frame  *Minibuf-1* 0x101899c30> (top (+ -568)) (left 1920) (width 177) (height 98))
```

and press `C-x 5 2` `(make-frame-command)`, I end up with frames like this:

```
(#<frame  *Minibuf-1* 0x108366c38> (top 23) (left 0) (width 80) (height 95))
(#<frame *scratch* 0x101899c30> (top (+ -568)) (left 1920) (width 177) (height 98))
```

I tried switching the order of `frame-inherited-parameters` to `(width height top left)` and ended up with this:

```
(#<frame  *Minibuf-1* 0x108374618> (width 80) (height 98) (top (+ -568)) (left 1920))
(#<frame *scratch* 0x101899c30> (width 177) (height 98) (top (+ -568)) (left 1920))
```

All of this happens even though I started emacs with `--no-init-file` and loaded no libraries since starting it.

Comment: Since you have already verified that this happens with `emacs -q`, then go ahead and submit a bug report.  MacOS Sierra is just too new.  It may or may not be OS related.  None of the emacs.stackexchange.com forum participants are going to suggest modifications of the C-source code, which is what might be needed to create a fix.

Comment: @lawlist I submitted a bug report with emacs -Q. I'm not sure if I should close this question or wait for a response and post it as an answer. Any guidance will be welcomed.

Comment: In the past, I have updated my own questions with the link to the bug report and then posted an answer several weeks or months later when the bug is resolved.  A few are years old and still have no resolution.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you actually use `frame-inherited-parameters` for? (I leave it `nil`.) Are you binding it during some execution? Or are you counting on it for default behavior (e.g., instead of customizing `default-frame-alist`).

Comment: @drew I use it to make new frames I create with `C-x 5 2` have the same size and position as the frame that was selected when I invoked the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been accepted as a bug in Emacs, but I don't have a lot of hope that someone is eager to fix it.  (I looked at it, but didn't have enough background to figure out what was happening.)  https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24651

If you, like me, actually used this feature, you can get a similar result by advising `(make-frame)`.  I did it like this:

```
(defun my-make-frame-advice (fcn &rest args)  
  (let* ((frm (selected-frame))  
         (geom-parms (mapcar (lambda (parm)  
                               (cons (parm (frame-parameter frm parm)))  
                             '(left top height width)))
         (new-frm (apply fcn args)))  
    (modify-frame-parameters new-frm geom-parms)
    new-frm))  

(advice-add #'make-frame :around #'my-make-frame-advice)
```

Comment: Edited so that "around" advice returned the newly-created frame. Otherwise, it would break stuff that called `make-frame` and used its value.